# Simple flow : using JDBC and File ( In Mule) but running in Loop

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm using JDBC inbound endpoint, withe the query to extract values from mysql and finally put it in to the file. I'm able to fetch the values in DB . But my flow is running unlimited times. can anyone help me.  Please find my configuration xml. Thanks in advance

```
<jdbc-ee:mysql-data-source name="MySQL_Data_Source" user="root" password="root" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="MySQL Data Source"/>
<jdbc-ee:connector name="Database" dataSource-ref="MySQL_Data_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database" transactionPerMessage="false"/>
<flow name="JDBCFlowFlow1" doc:name="JDBCFlowFlow1">
    <jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint queryKey="employeeSelect" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="1000" connector-ref="Database" doc:name="Database">
        <jdbc-ee:query key="employeeSelect" value="select * from employeedetails"/>
    <jdbc-ee:transaction action="NONE"/> 
    </jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="---------------Result: #[payload]------------------------" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\mule\OUTPUT FILE1" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Mule documentation of the JDBC Transport:

"Inbound SELECT queries are queries that are executed periodically (according to the pollingFrequency set on the connector)."

So the behavior you experience is to be expected.

A possible strategy to avoid periodical polling, is to create an inbound quartz-endpoint, where the 'repeatCount' is set to 1, and let a mule 'component' take care of the actual database retrieval.

Comment: Thank you @geby for the reply. But I dont want to take the record periodically form the DB. Just one time if it runs without loop is enough. So we cant use JDBC as inbound endpoint for select queries ( without using quartz) if so it run in loop?. Read Mulesoft document too.

Comment: Well you need a way to trigger the flow. You can either poll the database using a jdbc:inbound-endpoint or you can use quartz to schedule a jdbc:outbound-endpoint. Alternatively you could put another message source in front of the jdbc:outbound-endpoint such as http to trigger it via an api or similar or you could possibly write a component to get the endpoint and manually start/stop it or something. What's your usecase - how and when do you want to run this flow?

Comment: Thank you @RyanCarter i got the answer from your brief explanation. I'm new to Mule and exploring the Message processors as a kind of POC and i stuck in the above scenario . I try out the above said scenario's and work it out.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Poll component with a Cron expression would help any such scnearios because you can schedule the poll interval as required.The below link helps you for deciding the cron expression as per the requirement.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html